# While training image segmentation network UNET- Validation loss is not getting decreased after some epochs, remains constant

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, loss, unet-neural-network

I am training the UNET image segmentation network on brain tumor dataset from figshare, it is training well, **training loss** and **training dice score** both are changing accordingly or in the same tone with **validation loss** and **validation dice score**. Means no question of **Overfitting**. But after approximately **40 epochs** no improvement in performance measures. It's toggling around **loss 0.58 and dice score of 0.47**. ***How to solve this? Please suggest me.***
Below is my UNET network-

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (512,512,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    
    conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    #conv1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv1)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    #conv1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv1)
    
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    
    conv2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    #conv2 = Dropout(0.1)(conv2)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    #conv2 = Dropout(0.1)(conv2)
    
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    
    conv3 = Convolution2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    #conv3 = Dropout(0.1)(conv3)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    #conv3 = Dropout(0.1)(conv3)
    
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    
    conv4 = Convolution2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    #conv4 = Dropout(0.1)(conv4)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    #conv4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
        
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Convolution2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    #conv5 = Dropout(0.1)(conv5)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    #conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)
    

    up6 = Convolution2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv5))
    merge6 = concatenate([conv4,up6], axis = 3)
    
    conv6 = Convolution2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    #conv6 = Dropout(0.1)(conv6)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    #conv6 = Dropout(0.1)(conv6)

    up7 = Convolution2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    
    conv7 = Convolution2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    #conv7 = Dropout(0.1)(conv7)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    #conv7 = Dropout(0.1)(conv7)

    up8 = Convolution2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    
    conv8 = Convolution2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    #conv8 = Dropout(0.1)(conv8)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    #conv8 = Dropout(0.1)(conv8)

    up9 = Convolution2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    
    conv9 = Convolution2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    #conv9 = Dropout(0.2)(conv9)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    #conv9 = Dropout(0.2)(conv9)
    
    conv9 = Convolution2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    #conv9 = Dropout(0.2)(conv9)
    
    conv10 = Convolution2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

      
    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

Callback details initialized. Staring LR= 1e-4

```
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode="min", patience=30,verbose=1,min_delta=1e-4),
             ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',mode="min", factor=0.1,patience=8,verbose=1),
             ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss',mode="min",
                             filepath='weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-{epoch:03d}-{dice_coef:.6f}--{val_loss:.6f}.hdf5',save_weights_only=True, verbose=1),
             CSVLogger('weights/anmol/1/UNET_mixed_loss_monitor_DC_new.csv')]
```

My user-defined Dice Score and loss functions. I have used  dice_coef_loss here.

```
    def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
        y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
        y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    
    def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        loss = 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
        return loss
    
    def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Used 2605 images for training, 306 images for validation.
[Train_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM2f2.jpg) [Train_mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhKDK.jpg)

```
    img_size = 512

image_args = dict(seed=seed,
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode=None,
    target_size=(img_size, img_size),
    color_mode='rgb')

mask_args = dict(seed=seed,
    batch_size=2,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(img_size, img_size), 
    color_mode='grayscale')

DIR = 'raw/brain/'
image = 'images'
masks = 'masks'

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_datagen.flow_from_directory(**image_args, directory=DIR+'train_'+image),  
                      mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(**mask_args, directory=DIR+'train_'+masks))

validation_generator = zip(image_datagen.flow_from_directory(**image_args, directory=DIR+'validation_'+image),  
                      mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(**mask_args, directory=DIR+'validation_'+masks))

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=1302, epochs=100, validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=153, callbacks=callbacks)
```

**some training log shown below**

Epoch 00041: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-041-0.466533--0.511900.hdf5
Epoch 42/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5939 - dice_coef: 0.4658 - val_loss: 0.5076 - val_dice_coef: 0.5430

Epoch 00042: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-042-0.465990--0.507603.hdf5
Epoch 43/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5928 - dice_coef: 0.4678 - val_loss: 0.5191 - val_dice_coef: 0.5270

Epoch 00043: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-043-0.467685--0.519115.hdf5
Epoch 44/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5966 - dice_coef: 0.4632 - val_loss: 0.5158 - val_dice_coef: 0.5364

Epoch 00044: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-044-0.463308--0.515760.hdf5
Epoch 45/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5892 - dice_coef: 0.4702 - val_loss: 0.4993 - val_dice_coef: 0.5507

Epoch 00045: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-045-0.470134--0.499294.hdf5
Epoch 46/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5960 - dice_coef: 0.4636 - val_loss: 0.5166 - val_dice_coef: 0.5329

Epoch 00046: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-046-0.463810--0.516552.hdf5
Epoch 47/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5920 - dice_coef: 0.4672 - val_loss: 0.5062 - val_dice_coef: 0.5427

Epoch 00047: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-047-0.467146--0.506242.hdf5
Epoch 48/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5938 - dice_coef: 0.4657 - val_loss: 0.5239 - val_dice_coef: 0.5277

Epoch 00048: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-048-0.465866--0.523923.hdf5
Epoch 49/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5962 - dice_coef: 0.4639 - val_loss: 0.5035 - val_dice_coef: 0.5434

Epoch 00049: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-049-0.463924--0.503518.hdf5
Epoch 50/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5854 - dice_coef: 0.4743 - val_loss: 0.5463 - val_dice_coef: 0.5066

Epoch 00050: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-050-0.474530--0.546343.hdf5
Epoch 51/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5840 - dice_coef: 0.4749 - val_loss: 0.5146 - val_dice_coef: 0.5360

Epoch 00051: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-051-0.475072--0.514581.hdf5
Epoch 52/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5852 - dice_coef: 0.4742 - val_loss: 0.5257 - val_dice_coef: 0.5256

Epoch 00052: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-052-0.474234--0.525729.hdf5
Epoch 53/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5857 - dice_coef: 0.4736 - val_loss: 0.5157 - val_dice_coef: 0.5315

Epoch 00053: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 9.999999747378752e-07.

Epoch 00053: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-053-0.473557--0.515651.hdf5
Epoch 54/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5852 - dice_coef: 0.4737 - val_loss: 0.5067 - val_dice_coef: 0.5421

Epoch 00054: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-054-0.473682--0.506671.hdf5
Epoch 55/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5903 - dice_coef: 0.4696 - val_loss: 0.4910 - val_dice_coef: 0.5571

Epoch 00055: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-055-0.469478--0.491024.hdf5
Epoch 56/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5876 - dice_coef: 0.4711 - val_loss: 0.5154 - val_dice_coef: 0.5340

Epoch 00056: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-056-0.471110--0.515441.hdf5
Epoch 57/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5897 - dice_coef: 0.4703 - val_loss: 0.5263 - val_dice_coef: 0.5258

Epoch 00057: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-057-0.470255--0.526310.hdf5
Epoch 58/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5849 - dice_coef: 0.4741 - val_loss: 0.5067 - val_dice_coef: 0.5451

Epoch 00058: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-058-0.474262--0.506664.hdf5
Epoch 59/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5816 - dice_coef: 0.4769 - val_loss: 0.5160 - val_dice_coef: 0.5348

Epoch 00059: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-059-0.476830--0.516005.hdf5
Epoch 60/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5891 - dice_coef: 0.4709 - val_loss: 0.5179 - val_dice_coef: 0.5318

Epoch 00060: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-060-0.470746--0.517893.hdf5
Epoch 61/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5873 - dice_coef: 0.4727 - val_loss: 0.5064 - val_dice_coef: 0.5431

Epoch 00061: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-061-0.472722--0.506373.hdf5
Epoch 62/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5803 - dice_coef: 0.4793 - val_loss: 0.5187 - val_dice_coef: 0.5319

Epoch 00062: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-062-0.479199--0.518674.hdf5
Epoch 63/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1066s 819ms/step - loss: 0.5843 - dice_coef: 0.4738 - val_loss: 0.5052 - val_dice_coef: 0.5459

Epoch 00063: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 9.999999974752428e-08.

Epoch 00063: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-063-0.473731--0.505171.hdf5
Epoch 64/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5859 - dice_coef: 0.4731 - val_loss: 0.5064 - val_dice_coef: 0.5419

Epoch 00064: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-064-0.473008--0.506380.hdf5
Epoch 65/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1064s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5836 - dice_coef: 0.4752 - val_loss: 0.4997 - val_dice_coef: 0.5508

Epoch 00065: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-065-0.475424--0.499673.hdf5
Epoch 66/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 817ms/step - loss: 0.5932 - dice_coef: 0.4660 - val_loss: 0.5168 - val_dice_coef: 0.5338

Epoch 00066: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-066-0.465829--0.516758.hdf5
Epoch 67/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5820 - dice_coef: 0.4765 - val_loss: 0.5179 - val_dice_coef: 0.5323

Epoch 00067: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-067-0.476715--0.517926.hdf5
Epoch 68/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5912 - dice_coef: 0.4689 - val_loss: 0.5125 - val_dice_coef: 0.5375

Epoch 00068: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-068-0.468950--0.512456.hdf5
Epoch 69/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5820 - dice_coef: 0.4769 - val_loss: 0.5282 - val_dice_coef: 0.5237

Epoch 00069: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-069-0.476976--0.528154.hdf5
Epoch 70/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5845 - dice_coef: 0.4743 - val_loss: 0.5204 - val_dice_coef: 0.5303

Epoch 00070: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-070-0.474195--0.520356.hdf5
Epoch 71/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1063s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5886 - dice_coef: 0.4708 - val_loss: 0.5230 - val_dice_coef: 0.5270

Epoch 00071: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 1.0000000116860975e-08.

Epoch 00071: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-071-0.470715--0.523011.hdf5
Epoch 72/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 816ms/step - loss: 0.5837 - dice_coef: 0.4759 - val_loss: 0.5216 - val_dice_coef: 0.5303

Epoch 00072: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-072-0.475787--0.521631.hdf5
Epoch 73/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1062s 815ms/step - loss: 0.5804 - dice_coef: 0.4780 - val_loss: 0.5333 - val_dice_coef: 0.5171

Epoch 00073: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-073-0.478063--0.533321.hdf5
Epoch 74/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1065s 818ms/step - loss: 0.5842 - dice_coef: 0.4747 - val_loss: 0.5126 - val_dice_coef: 0.5393

Epoch 00074: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-074-0.474628--0.512649.hdf5
Epoch 75/100
1302/1302 [==============================] - 1069s 821ms/step - loss: 0.5836 - dice_coef: 0.4755 - val_loss: 0.5103 - val_dice_coef: 0.5386

Epoch 00075: saving model to weights/anmol/1/UNET_sigmoid_focus_DC_2605_R_B_t-075-0.475690--0.510267.hdf5
Epoch 76/100
160/1302 [==>...........................] - ETA: 15:02 - loss: 0.6069 - dice_coef: 0.4548
​

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63439018/edit) the post to include the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which means also a sample of your images and masks also your train_generator, because we don't know some critical information such as: how many images per batch!.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan thank you for your reply. I have edited the question according to your demand. Batch size= 2  as I am having GPU limitations. And train image and mask sample uploaded...please check and suggest...

Comment: Batch size= 2 will not give a good results! you may need to increase the Batch number to 8 at least!

Comment: @BelalHomaidan is this the only solution? or shall I go for more number of training images ??(currently having 2605)?? Because of Hardware limitation can't go beyond batch size of 2 gives me memory error?

Comment: the other solution is to try PyTorch instead because it allocates the memory dynamically not statically like Keras or TF

Comment: @Bilal sir I trained UNET with larger batch size i.e 9, 16 also with 32, still performance is not increasing. Dice score stuck in between 0/52 to 0.53. Even I tried with Augmentation (from 2605 samples to 7815 samples to 13025 samples) still performance is not getting improved. Overall I never jump beyond the dice score 0.56.... please help me...